# Draw rectangles with different scales in R

Tags: r, scale

I want to draw two rectangles that are connected by a series of lines. However, the size of the top rectangle is 157 while the bottom one is 75.

I don't want the bottom one appears smaller but to draw them with different scales as shown in the graph.

[image]

How could I achieve this in R?

Thanks!